# Python - cannot import `linalg`

Tags: python, import

I have this code

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import numpy as np

id = np.eye(13)
vals, vecs = sparse.linalg.eigsh(id, k=6)
vals
```

which is just the example code from the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html).

I am running it in a Python 2.7 console and I get the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'linalg'

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code

```
import scipy.sparse.linalg as sp
import numpy as np

id = np.eye(13)
vals, vecs = sp.eigsh(id, k=6)
vals
```

This happens because `linalg` is a directory and not source code i.e it is a sub-package. And I guess this causes the issue because some of the Scipy sub modules do not have `__init__.py`, Maybe the devs did this to reduce loading times of top-level packages. You can find this information in Scipy Organization section in this [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/general.html)

Comment: Now it says `ImportError: No module named eigsh`

Comment: Try `import scipy.sparse.linalg as sp` and replace `vals, vecs = sp(id, k=6)` with `vals, vecs = sp.eigsh(id, k=6)`

Comment: Added a few more details to the answer. hope it helps